# Is There An Alternative To Android Recycler Views?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm working on an android project and it requires something like the functionality found in the recycler view. However the recycler view requires android 5.0.1 API 21 which will reduce the amount of devices that can use it. I was wondering if anyone knew of any substitutions I might be able to use in lieu of the recylcer view? I've linked to a small video of what the view would be attempting to accomplish.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8alYNlu3SuoSEk0bE55cDhXWVE

Comment: Check out the [RecyclerView support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-recyclerview). Also, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Have you looked into the appcompat library?

Comment: [Remember to accept the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: Posted the answer below.

Comment: `RecyclerView` is provided by a library which works on API 7+ (Android 2.1). The alternative is the good old `ListView` or `GridView`, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Turns out I don't need an alternative, my dependencies were incorrect! Thanks though.

Comment: If you want an easier/reusable implementation of the RecycleView that accepts any views; look into this lib: https://github.com/voidstarfire/enhanced-recycle-list-android

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However the recycler view requires android 5.0.1 API 21

No, it does not. `recyclerview-v7` works back to API Level 7. Hence, if you want `RecyclerView` functionality, use `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Yeah, something is wrong with my dependencies. I was asking the wrong questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `ListView` here you are few tutorials
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
And this one for creating custom listviews 
http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

Comment: I suspected this to be my only alternative, but I was not sure if it could accomplish the same type of view. In your opinion, could it?

Comment: @Eidenai Yeah, a frame for the item then put `ImageView`, `TextView` and a `Button`

Comment: ListView would probably be simpler for your usecase anyway, though as pointed out, RecyclerView is available from API 7 onwards using the recyclerview-v7 support library.

Answer (score 0):

My dependencies were as follows:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
```

They should have been:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

Comment: You really should have a version code in there, just not a release candidate. They are each up to 23.0.1 IIRC.

Comment: Roger that. I'm still trying to get it to work with the original dependencies it just kept the build from failing. I'm still trying to figure out what the problem is to be honest. It otherwise says failed to resolve both views.

Comment: I have a bunch of `RecyclerView` samples. Here's one that also uses `CardView`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/CardRippleList3 This happens to be still using 22.2.0, but I know it works.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I'll check it out. I still have to figure out why I can't use the packages >.>